# Plotting markers on maps in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to mark a certain number of cities on a map in MATLAB.
I got the country outline using borders.
But I have tried to use textm, plot, symbol and nothing points up a marker on the cities.

Here is my short code (I am just trying with one city)

```
figure
%worldmap('botswana')
borders('botswana','linewidth',2) % outlines Botswana
%text(24.65,25.91, 'Gaborone')

%plot(24.65,25.91, 'bo', 'MarkerSize', '10', 'LineWidth', '2')
%plotm(24.65,25.91)

%h2 = wmmarker(24.65, 25.91, 'Featurename', 'gabororne')

% places = {'Gaborone';'Francistown'};
% lats = [24.69 21.17];
% lons = [25.91 27.51];
% 
% textm(lats,lons,places,'vert','middle',...
%     'horiz','center','color','b')
```

Would appreciate any help. (I was trying one method at a time, hence the code is in commented form)

Comment: Try [scatter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html) and [annotation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html).

Comment: Which `borders` function are you using - something off the file exchange? You should look into how exactly that is doing the plotting, might be using something in the mapping toolbox.

Comment: Yes, I used file exchange and I did study the function. I have the mapping toolbox, besides, the documentation mentions that we dont need the mapping toolbox for this.